# How should I append a newly created element to the next to last position of another element using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to append a newly created div into the next to last position of an element but I am a beginner and I'm not quite sure how to select that position.

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.className = "test";
div.innerHTML = "some stuff";
document.getElementById('content').appendChild(div);
```

Comment: show more code, please make a JSfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.className = "test";
div.innerHTML = "some stuff";
var parent    = document.getElementById('content');
var children  = parent.children;

parent.insertBefore(div, children[children.length-1]);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/SL76g/)